# Prove $[L(\alpha) : L]$ divides $[K(\alpha):K]$ for L finite normal extension of K

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

We are also given $\alpha$ belongs to a finite extension of L.

With the tower law, I get:

$[L(\alpha):L][L:K] = [L(\alpha):K]$
and $[L(\alpha):K(\alpha)][K(\alpha):K] = [L(\alpha):K]$

But I'm stuck from here. Any hints?

Comment: Factorize in $L[x]$ the $K$-minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. What can you say of the degrees of the irreducible factors ?

Comment: @reuns So if I do as you suggested, and have $m_{\alpha, K}(x)$ as the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over K, then when I factorize it in $L[x]$ we have two cases. In particular, if the K-minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ has no roots in L, then the factorization will be the same so $[L(\alpha):L] = [K(\alpha):K]$ and if there is a root in L, since L is a normal extension it will split completely in $L[x]$ so $[L(\alpha):L] = 1$ and the result still holds. Is this correct?

Comment: That a polynomial is not irreducible doesn't mean it has a root

Comment: @reuns So my first case is incorrect? If the K-minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ has no roots in L, then the factorization in $L[x]$ could be reducible? Then I have to justify why the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ viewed over L has degree that divides the K-minimal polynomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N/K$ be the normal closure of $L(\alpha)/K$ and $f(x)\in K[x]$ the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. Factorize it over $L$
$$f(x)=  \prod_j f_j(x)^{e_j}\in L[x]$$
Wlog $f_1$ is the $L$-minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. For each remaining $f_j(x)$ pick one of its root $\alpha_j\in N$. Then
$f_j(x)$ is the $L$-minimal polynomial of $\alpha_j\in N$ which is a root of $f$. Thus, $\alpha_j$ is $K$-conjugate to $\alpha$ so there is some $\sigma_j\in Aut(N/K)$ such that $\sigma_j(\alpha_j)=\alpha$. Since $L/K$ is normal then $\sigma_j(L)=L$.

> This implies that $f_j^{\sigma_j}(x),f_1(x)$ are both irreducible $\in L[x]$ and have a common root $\alpha$, therefore  $f_j^{\sigma_j}(x)=f_1(x)$,$\deg(f_j)=\deg(f_1)$,  $$[L(\alpha):L]=\deg(f_1)\ \ | \ \deg(f)=[K(\alpha):K]$$